# How to corner top bar chart

Tags: java, android, mpchart

I want to only round the 2 upper corners of the barchart as shown in the photo

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf47o.png)

But when I search for a way to handle it, the result I get is using drawRoundRect, but using this function will round all 4 corners.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.